# JPA não persiste o Objeto no banco

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Estou com um problema no qual eu tento persistir dados no Banco com JPA e hibernate só que ele não persiste o Objeto.

Ele cria a tabela mas não persiste os dados e nenhuma exceção é apresentada.

Segue a baixo como estou fazendo:

```
public class ArtesaoDAO {

public void salvar(Artesao artesao){
   // EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction(); 
    EntityManager manager = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
     manager.getTransaction().begin();

    try {
        manager.persist(artesao);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }catch(Exception e){
        manager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally{
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Como eu falei a tabela é criada mas o Objeto artesão não é persistido.

Fiz uma modificação no meu DAO:

```
@Transactional
public class ArtesaoDAO{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "portifoliows")
    private EntityManager manager;


    public void salvar(Artesao artesao){
       System.out.print(artesao.getNome());

        try {
           this.manager.persist(artesao);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           this.manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }catch(Exception e){
            this.manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public void deletar(Artesao artesao){

    }


}
```

Ele apresenta a seguinte exceção:

```
Grave:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ratossi.portifoliows.controllers.CadastroController.cadastrar(CadastroController.java:43)
at com.ratossi.portifoliows.controllers.CadastroController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.cadastrar(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Meu Controller de Cadastro:

```
@Controller
public class CadastroController {
    @Inject
    private Result result;

    //Função para cadastar artesao

   @Path("/cadastro")
   @Post
   public void cadastrar(Artesao artesao){
      try {
        result.include("artesao", "id:"+artesao.getId()+" Nome: "+artesao.getNome()+" Login:"+artesao.getLogin()+" Senha: "+artesao.getSenha());
        System.out.print("Persistindo -- > "+"id:"+artesao.getId()+" Nome: "+artesao.getNome()+" Login:"+artesao.getLogin()+" Senha: "+artesao.getSenha());
        ArtesaoDAO artesaoDAO = new ArtesaoDAO();
        artesaoDAO.salvar(artesao);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Nenhum erro é apresentando, mesmo se você imprimir a *stack trace* das exceções que você recupera?

Comment: Como o Bruno disse, imprime o erro dentro dos 2 catch (`Null` e `Exception`) dessa forma é mais fácil de identificar o problema

Comment: Obrigado vou fazer isso e vê se ele encontra alguma exceção.

Comment: Eu achei estranha a forma como você faz a transação. Uma pergunta: no seu datasource, que tipo de transação você usa: Resource_Local ou JTA? Outra coisa: Poste também a entidade mapeada.

Comment: Edgar estou usando JTA.

Comment: O que tem na linha 43 de `CadastroController`? Talvez seja interessante incluir o método `cadastrar`(e atributos relevantes da classe) para vermos o que é, aparentemente nem está chegando ao seu DAO, então pode ser algum problema de injeção de dependência no seu controller.

Comment: Linha 43 artesaoDAO.salvar(artesao);

Comment: Certo, então `artesaoDAO` está nulo. Você provavelmente está usando inversão de controle (isando `@Inject`). Se for isto mesmo, como está ativando o container CDI?

Comment: @DarlanOliveira não edite a resposta dos usuários adicionando duvidas, edite a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minhas sugestões:

> Faça a injeção do DAO para ele ser registrado pelo container e ter as
>   dependências injetadas.

```
@Controller
public class CadastroController {
    @Inject
    private Result result;
    @Inject
    private ArtesaoDAO artesaoDAO;       

    //Função para cadastar artesao

   @Path("/cadastro")
   @Post
   public void cadastrar(Artesao artesao){
      try {
        result.include("artesao", "id:"+artesao.getId()+" Nome: "+artesao.getNome()+" Login:"+artesao.getLogin()+" Senha: "+artesao.getSenha());
        System.out.print("Persistindo -- > "+"id:"+artesao.getId()+" Nome: "+artesao.getNome()+" Login:"+artesao.getLogin()+" Senha: "+artesao.getSenha());

        artesaoDAO.salvar(artesao);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

No DAO:

> Lembrando que a anotation @Transactional e assim o suporte para
>   injeção do @PersistenceContext pelo container, fora de um EJB só e
>   suportado no JEE7 e JTA 1.2.

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class ArtesaoDAO{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "portifoliows")
    private EntityManager manager;


    public void salvar(Artesao artesao){
       System.out.print(artesao.getNome());

        try {
           this.manager.persist(artesao);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           this.manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }catch(Exception e){
            this.manager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public void deletar(Artesao artesao){

    }

}
```

**Sobre o DAO que não "comitou":**

> Nesse caso você teria de ter obtido a userTransaction do contexto **(BMT
>   - Bean Managed Transaction)** a ter iniciado e posteriormente ter criado o entity manager ou feito um **entityManager.joinTransaction** dentro
>   da transação JTA.

```
public class ArtesaoDAO {

public void salvar(Artesao artesao){
    EntityManager manager = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    ut = (UserTransaction) ctx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");

    try {
        ut.begin();
        manager.joinTransaction();
        manager.persist(artesao);
        ut.commit();

    }catch(Exception e){
        ut.rollback();
    }finally{
        manager.close();
    }
}
```